# Background web upload flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, plugins

First sorry for my bad English...

I want to do a flutter App that can upload large file to server but I want a background task (the upload will continue when navigate on the app). The main problem is that i am looking for an app that works on both mobile and web.

Ty

I've try to use workers but it's difficult to stream it and I have to code different function for web.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.